# P/Invoke signature for sched_setscheduler

Tags: c#, linux, mono, pinvoke

I need to come up with the P/Invoke signature for the Linux [`sched_setaffinity`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) function, to be called from C# code running on Mono.

```
int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t cpusetsize,
                      cpu_set_t *mask);
```

The [`ThreadAffinity`](https://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/source/browse/trunk/Hardware/ThreadAffinity.cs?r=418) class in the "open-hardware-monitor" project defines it as:

```
[DllImport(LIBC)]
public static extern int sched_setaffinity(int pid, IntPtr maskSize,
                                           ref ulong mask);
```

However, the [Mono.LibRt](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/46/size/110595/name/mono-librt-0.1.2-16.20.src.rpm) project uses a different signature:

```
[DllImport (LIBC, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
                  SetLastError=true, EntryPoint="sched_setaffinity")]
protected static extern int sched_setaffinity (long pid, int num_bytes, 
                                               byte[] affinity);
```

Are both signatures correct, or is one erroneous? Are they portable across 32- and 64-bit architectures?

I assume that the first argument should be `int`, not `long`, since `pid_t` is a signed 32-bit integer on both 32- and 64-bit platforms (per [Joe Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922775/1149773)). Similarly, the second should be `UIntPtr` or `IntPtr` per [Patrick McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/q/772531/1149773). However, I don't know how to handle the third parameter.

**Edit**: Building on Simon Mourier's comment: I gather, from the `cpu_set_t *` type, that the third parameter should be a pointer. Does `ref ulong` qualify? I'm tempted to use that type because it makes the macros easier to implement; for example, a mask for a single processor `id` can be computed as:

```
ulong mask = 1UL << id;
```

I've found a definition for `cpu_set_t` in this [`sched.h`](http://linux.die.net/include/bits/sched.h), where it's implemented as an array of `unsigned long int`.

Comment: I agree on `int pid` and `IntPtr maskSize`. For the cpu_set_t I suppose it defaults to C `int` since it's not defined explicitly in sched.h. What's important is it has to be a pointer, and this pointer must be manipulated by the internal CPU_* macros (CPU_ZERO, etc.). So you can use byte[] or int[], but you need to expose the CPU_* macros to the .NET world as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, cpu_set_t is simply an array of unsigned long int. So I would declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport("libc.so.6", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int sched_setaffinity(
    int pid, 
    IntPtr cpusetsize, 
    ulong[] cpuset
);
```

Comment: Thanks David! I assume `cpusetsize` should be the size of the entire array (e.g. `4 * sizeof(ulong)` if it contains four elements)?

Comment: (It'll take me a couple of weeks to test the answer; I don't currently have access to the Linux machine.)

Answer (score 0):

Per my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17124433/1149773), I went with the former option (which worked fine on Linux).

```
[DllImport("libc.so.6", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int sched_setaffinity(int pid, IntPtr cpusetsize, 
                                            ref ulong cpuset);
```

Comment: The problem is that `cpu_set_t` could be larger than a `ulong`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That would require a machine larger than a 64-core, no?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Granted, but most programmers are not likely to encounter them in the next few years. Even the .NET Framework's [`ProcessorAffinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx) would break on such machines.